# Сreating your own class of integers

Tags: c++

I have written a function that finds numbers in the substitutions and sums them modulo 256.

```
__int64_t String_solver(string str){
    __int64_t i_a = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.size(); i++){
        int j = 0;
        if(isdigit(str[i])){
            j=i;
            while(isdigit(str[i])){
                i++;
            }
            const char * c = str.substr (j,i-j).c_str();
            i_a+= strtoll(c, nullptr,10);
        }
        else if((str[i]=='-')&&(isdigit(str[i+1]))){
            j=i;
            i++;
            while(isdigit(str[i])){
                i++;
            }
            const char * c = str.substr (j,i-j).c_str();
            i_a+= strtoll(c, nullptr,10);
        }
    }
    return i_a;
}

int main() {
    __int64_t arg=0;
    string string1;
    std::ifstream in("text.txt");
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(in, string1))
        {
            arg+=String_solver(string1);
        }
    }
    in.close();
    if(arg<0){
        cout << (arg % 256 + 256) % 256;
    }
    else{
        cout << arg%256;}
    return 0;
}
```

But this program does not work correctly with the following file
text.txt

```
12123
123123
123124234345
23423453465467345234
234234234234234
234234234234
-234234234234
-2134234234234287492847923847
```

I do not understand why _int_64_t is not a suitable type.

Comment: Could you indicate  `String_solver` return value for each line ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `long long`?   Unlike `_int_64_t` it is standard, and supports (at least) the same range of values as a 64-bit signed integer.   In any event, the last value in your file is too large (in magnitude) to be represented using a 64-bit type.   Which means, among other things that `strtoull()` is not guaranteed to handle that line correctly.

Comment: @Peter: note that `long long` *might* have one fewer negative number if it's not 2's complement. Cf. the standard `int64_t` which must be 2's complement. `-_int_64_t` is of course not defined by the standards.

Comment: You are only interested in the final modulo 256 value. Therefore, you can read the digit one by one and calculate recursively the modulo 256 value, something like `x = (10*x + newdigit) %256;`.

Comment: long long also not helpful, it's return 48 but must be 252

Comment: @СтаниславИванников  - as I said, your input value will NOT fit in a 64-bit int, and there is also no guarantee that a `long long` will represent it.     If you expect your code to work with large values, you need to use an approach that can handle such large values correctly.   You are not.

Comment: `const char * c = str.substr (j,i-j).c_str();` -- this line creates a temporary string object (`substr`), takes a pointer to its internal storage (`c_str()`), and then destroys the temporary object. `c` is a dangling pointer. If this code "works" it's only by accident.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand why _int_64_t is not a suitable type.

If you look at what is the biggest value you can store in a _int64_t : 
`2^64 = 18446744073709551616` which you'll have to divide by 2 so that you can get negative values `18446744073709551616/2 = 9223372036854775808`. Which means that the maximal value you can get is `9223372036854775808` and minimal value is `-9223372036854775808` however your lowest value is `-2134234234234287492847923847`. That's why _int64_t is not suitable.

That said, as we don't really know what's wrong with your output it's hard to say if this is the real problem.

Comment: You could try to implement a sort of scientific notation class ([such as this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) ) you'd have 2 attributes, exponent and coefficient. But that would mean you'd have to re-implement addition and modulo operator. I really do not think that is worth it. As stated in the comments, since you are interested **only** on modulo 256 values a workaround is preferable.

Comment: @СтаниславИванников You may want to look at [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). It provides an arbitrary precision integer that can do what you want. Of course, that flexibility comes at a (runtime) cost, so you'll have to determine whether this is acceptable for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and the first answer, your type is not long enough for your large inputs.

You are only interested in the final modulo 256 value. Therefore, you can read the digit one by one and calculate recursively the modulo 256 value, something like `x = (10*x + newdigit) %256;`

Just pay attention to deal with the sign for first affection of `x`.